# Java 2D Graphics - priority of items in paintComponent

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, paintcomponent, java-2d

i have a simple question. I'm new to the Java 2D API so my question is:

Is there anyway to manually set the priority of something being drawn within paintComponent()   ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you draw will be the furthest back. So

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 80, 30); // Drawn in back
    g.drawRect(20, 20, 70, 40); // Drawn in middle
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10); // Drawn in front
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wish to call a function that will remove everything from the paint component screen then start adding back stuff. However, when i use a clearRect() function, it clears the screen but i'm not getting to paint over that.

Comment: You're calling clearRect() before calling drawRect() correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you tell Java to draw something first, It will be drawn first and anything you draw on top of that will be drawn over the first thing you drew.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify a priority but you can specify the order (in the order code) in which each object is drawn. [Here](http://www.garybeene.com/3d/3d-java.htm) is a example.

```
public void paint(Graphics screen) {
    sortByDepth(screen);
    backFaceCulling(screen);
    applyProjection(screen);
    drawCube(screen);
}
```

The following book can help a lot: [Introduction to
Computer Graphics Using Java 2D and 3D](http://www.springer.com/computer/image+processing/book/978-1-4471-2732-1). Additionally, you may want to see [Visible Surface Determination](http://what-when-how.com/introduction-to-computer-graphics-using-java-2d-and-3d/visible-surface-determination-introduction-to-computer-graphics-using-java-2d-and-3d-part-3/) if you want to draw something like this:

[image: Overlapping polygons here]

See also:

- [Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm)